# Angular Js : How to get next state

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created state sequentially, and my pages are in that sequence.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("Cars", {
    url: "",
  })
  .state("Drivers", {
    url: "/step2",
})
```

When I click on next link I want to redirect to next state. instead of hard-coded or writing new mapping.

`$state.current.name` gives current state and `$state.go()` returns list of all states.

I tried to set param as below

$stateProvider.state('Cars', {
    url: '/cars',
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    params: {
        nextPage: "Drivers"
    }
})

But getting error. **Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module autoQuote due to:
Invalid params in state 'Cars'
$StateProvider/stateBuilder.params@http://dev.easyquote.insurance.com/hqx/min/?g=easyquote-js&v=1:1206:33**

I am using Angular Js version: 1.5.7

How to find here next state?